# Query to Update data to table with value from other table column with if condition in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Good Morning everyone. I'm just new to Laravel. I started to learn Laravel since 2 months ago with basic programming skill.

Currently, I have two table.

First the main table. `movies`. I have lots of column but I will use some of them that is related to this question.

| id | ship_no | delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 |  |
| 2 | 1111 |  |
| 3 | 1122 |  |
| 4 | 1234 |  |

Second, I have `shipment_report` table that contain distict data of shipment_no and the delivery_date information

| id | shipment_no | pack_date | ship_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 12/06/23 | 13/06/23 |
| 2 | 1122 | 14/06/23 |  |

My goal is to update `movies` table at column `delivery_date` using value from table `shipment_report` where the `ship_no` column value from `movies` table match `shipment_no` value from `shipment_report` table. Then use value from column with if condition. If column `ship_date` !='' (not empty), use value column `ship_date`. If that column is empty at that row, use value from column `pack_date`.

So the updated table must be like this :

| id | ship_no | delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 13/06/23 |
| 2 | 1111 | 13/06/23 |
| 3 | 1122 | 14/06/23 |
| 4 | 1234 |  |

I can achieve this result using plain query like this :

```
    DB::update("UPDATE
    `movies`
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        `shipment_no`
    FROM
        `shipment_report`
) AS `shipment_report`
ON
    `movies`.`ship_no` = `shipment_report`.`shipment_no`
SET
    `movies`.`delivery_date` = IF(
        `shipment_report`.`ship_date` != '',
        `shipment_report`.`ship_date`,
        `shipment_report`.`pack_date`)
WHERE
    `movies`.`ship_no` = `shipment_report`.`shipment_no`;");
```

I know that the above code is so ugly especially in Laravel.

I've tried two method in Laravel style.
First :

```
 DB::table('movies')
    ->leftJoin('shipment_report','movies.ship_no', '=', 'shipment_report.shipment_no')
    ->update(((DB::raw('shipment_report.ship_date'))!='' ?
    [
                'movies.delivery_date'=>DB::raw('shipment_report.ship_date')
                ]:[
                    'movies.delivery_date'=>DB::raw('shipment_report.pack_date')
                ]));
```

Second :

```
    $shipDate = DB::raw('shipment_report.ship_date');
    $packDate = DB::raw('shipment_report.pack_date');

    if(!is_empty($shipDate)){

    DB::table('movies')
    ->leftJoin('shipment_report','movies.ship_no', '=', 'shipment_report.shipment_no')
    ->update([  
                'movies.delivery_date'=>$shipDate
            ]);
    }else{
        DB::table('movies')
        ->leftJoin('shipment_report','movies.ship_no', '=', 'shipment_report.shipment_no')
        ->update([  
                    'movies.delivery_date'=>$packDate
                ]);
```

Those two method that I've tried resulted the same behavior. But, it is opposite from the plain query as I mention at the first code I showed in this question.

With plain Query, `!=''` will result the `delivery_date` value of `id = 1` with value from `ship_date` because `!=''` detect that the `delivery_date` is not empty, so use the value.
And at `id=2` in`movies` table, use the `pack_date` value because the `ship_date` is empty.

With those two Laravel style above, I got always the result of `ship_date` value. Even the value is empty, the query will use that column. I think laravel style `!=''` or `is_empty()` from column `ship_date` detected that the column has a value.

Please help me to get the right thing in Laravel-wise query.

Your help will be very appreciated. Thank You.